# Start app in Heroku (Maven)

Tags: java, rest, maven, heroku

I am trying to start an app on Heroku but I am facing an issue, I will tell step by step what I did to arrive at this point, if someone help me I will be very help and I will send a chocolate cake :D

First I create my maven project in Eclipse, in my localhost, everything went ok.

So I send the code to github : 
https://github.com/ViniMartinPS/olimpiadas

But I dont think the code will be very helpfull here, in my head, the problem is configs.

I create my app in Heroku and did the deploy using the git code, no problems, deploy OK. I also downloaded 2 plugins : Heroku Postgree and JawsDB MySQL, but I didnt change anything. My code is just a test to see if Heroku is working for me.

So, I thought was everything ok to test but I have the error message when I tried to access the page:

" An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

And I have that in the log :

```
2016-08-23T19:00:49.102379+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/games/webapi/jogos/esporte1" host=thawing-temple-28369.herokuapp.com request_id=f5edce97-25b5-4b6a-8139-47c6083260c9 fwd="179.132.109.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-08-23T19:00:49.588961+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=thawing-temple-28369.herokuapp.com request_id=f0c3ff79-2d70-4fa7-ad0a-b810ec9a6d38 fwd="179.132.109.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Then I research to see about Dynos/Procfiles and I tried to create one and paste into Heroku:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/olimpiadas/games/MyResource
```

MyResource is a class example that I have in my project.

then I restart the dynos :

```
2016-08-23T19:03:10.002566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-08-23T19:03:12.998462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/olimpiadas/games/MyResource`
2016-08-23T19:03:15.501843+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-08-23T19:03:15.506279+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2016-08-23T19:03:15.728591+00:00 app[web.1]:            (to execute a jar file)
2016-08-23T19:03:15.728598+00:00 app[web.1]:     -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
2016-08-23T19:03:15.728603+00:00 app[web.1]:     -version      print product version and exit
2016-08-23T19:03:15.728604+00:00 app[web.1]:     -version:<value>
2016-08-23T19:03:15.728609+00:00 app[web.1]:                   in a future release.
2016-08-23T19:03:15.728613+00:00 app[web.1]:     -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
2016-08-23T19:03:15.728618+00:00 app[web.1]:                   see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
2016-08-23T19:03:15.841736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-08-23T19:03:15.875119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-08-23T19:03:15.876084+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-08-23T19:03:18.382238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/olimpiadas/games/MyResource`
2016-08-23T19:03:20.004342+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-08-23T19:03:20.009058+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401910+00:00 app[web.1]: Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401923+00:00 app[web.1]:            (to execute a class)
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401924+00:00 app[web.1]:    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401928+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401929+00:00 app[web.1]:     -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401930+00:00 app[web.1]:     -D<name>=<value>
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401934+00:00 app[web.1]:                   Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401938+00:00 app[web.1]:                   disable assertions with specified granularity
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401940+00:00 app[web.1]:                   load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
2016-08-23T19:03:20.401947+00:00 app[web.1]: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
2016-08-23T19:03:20.459704+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-08-23T19:03:20.459575+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have the same error if I try to use the page again. Probably this Procfile is wrong, or I need to add something else about databases, I dont know.

Can someone help me ? I really need to deploy this application, I will be very happy :)

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you deploying with Git or the Maven plugin? Is your `Procfile` committed to Git (run `git ls-files` to confirm)?

Comment: Nevermind, the `Starting process with command` in the logs confirms that it is

Comment: What is shown when you run `heroku config:get JAVA_OPTS`?

Comment: @codefinger , I am deploying with GIT, and the procfile is in Git too. I confirmed using this command too.

Comment: @codefinger , I tried to use this config:get and returned me blank :(

Comment: that's actually what i would expect (blank)

Comment: Can you confirm that the files exists in the heroku slug by running `heroku run ls target/olimpiadas/games/MyResource` and `heroku run ls target/classes`?

Comment: @codefinger the first one doesnt exist, I changed to target/classes/olimpiadas/games/MyResource , and got the same error, the second one exist

Comment: i think maybe you want `java -cp target/classes olimpiadas.games.MyResource`

Comment: @codefinger I tested this and have the same error. What should I put on this Procfile ? what is the meaning of this file ? Only put the main class ? This one that I have, I saw one example and I thought this should work, maybe I need something more or less in this file. How do I need to put to create one that work ?

Comment: Are you following a guide? can you share the link?

Comment: no. Until the deploy, I was doing by myself reading the dashboard. After I get an error, I start searching about the Dynos and Procfiles but I didnt gove any step foward with this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the command in the `Procfile`, but I'm not certain what it is. To start, reduce your `Procfile` to just this:

```
web: java -cp target/classes:target/olimpiadas/games/MyResource
```

**EDIT**

I just realized this command has no main class. that is the problem. Is `olimpiadas.games.MyResource` your main class?

Comment: That is MyResource class:

Answer (score 0):

@codefinger

thats my MyResource:

```
package olimpiadas.games;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not a main class. you need a class that has a `public static void main` method.